# Does Triggers inside control template or style have orders?

Tags: wpf

Is there any order of execution for the trigger inside a controlTemplate of Style?. eg. IsMouseOver trigger should comes first after that IsSelected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Triggers are evaluated in the order they are declared, so if multiple triggers set the same property then only the last one will take effect.  If they are setting different properties then the order does not matter.